# Using a variable to call up a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, variables, filter

I'm trying to use a cell value (a department and skills from a value list) to switch to the correct department worksheet and apply a filter using the skill variables vS1 - vS4.  Using the macro record I can get the correct code for selecting a specific worksheet etc but when I try and replace the name with a variable I fail.  The code is as follows:

```
Set vDept = Range("U18")
Set vS1 = Range("C2")
Set vS2 = Range("D2")
Set vS3 = Range("E2")
Set vS4 = Range("F2")

If vDept = "vDept" Then
    Worksheets("vDept").Select
    Worksheets vDept.Activate
End If
```

Comment: Lots missing here. No Dim statement for any of your variables. Select is using the text  "vDept" instead of the text in the cell, vDept.Value. No clue what you're trying to accomplish with the 2nd Worksheets command inside the If.  You have the right idea, but the syntax of your implementation is slightly off in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the code below, it has clarifications on the steps you need to follow :

```
Option Explicit


Sub DefineObjectsFirst()

' define all Range Objects
Dim vDept As Range, vS1 As Range, vS2 As Range, vS3 As Range, vS4 As Range

Set vDept = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U18")  ' <-- replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name

' same applies to all Range objects below
Set vS1 = Range("C2")
Set vS2 = Range("D2")
Set vS3 = Range("E2")
Set vS4 = Range("F2")

' check if range value is "vDept"
If vDept.Value = "vDept" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vDept.Value).Activate  ' Select the sheet (only if necessary)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That’s great Shai Rado, very much appreciated.